# How can the "Save File" dialog window of Chrome to be set to focus when saving?

Tags: google-chrome, focus, dialog

Recently, I've found that the "Save File" dialog window of Google Chrome is not in focus after selecting something for saving from a context menu.

This *used* to be the behavior and I find that it is actually disrupting how I work: instead of selecting something for saving and then being able to press Enter to save, I am forced to focus the "Save File" window and then to select the Save button using the mouse (selecting it using Tab, as bad as this would be, is not even working).

How can the original behavior of being able to press Enter to save a file be instated again?

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.1 with Google Chrome 38.0.2125.104 (64-bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recent update appears to have changed this behaviour back to what it was. :)

---

EDIT: I'm observing this behaviour in 39.0.2171.71 in Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: Great news if true. Can you add a version number for which this happens?

Comment: I've added the details as requested.

Comment: Still have this issue on Ubuntu 21.10 and Chrome 97.0.4692.99.