# How to make Chrome browser "Save as" dialog to be on focus when opening under Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: shortcut-keys, google-chrome, window, focus

I use Ubuntu 21.04 and bumped exactly in the issue that seem to be [solved long ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541376/how-can-the-save-file-dialog-window-of-chrome-to-be-set-to-focus-when-saving)... under 14.04 version. But now it's back. I use Chrome 94.0.4606.61（Official Build）and when open "Save as..." dialog, I'd rather prefer to just hit Enter button to confirm my choice. Instead it's not on focus, so I have to move my cursor to the Save button and press it, since no hotkeys let me focus this dialogue.

Would appreciate is anybody could advice me how to fix it under Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: I see the same, in Google Chrome, Chromium flatpak and Firefox flatpak

Comment: I see the same on my Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS with MATE and deb-packaged Chromium. Reported a [bug](https://pad.lv/1949340). Offered a bounty here to get a fix.

Comment: I'm not going to add this as an answer, because it's not - it's a workaround at best. That said, if you want to keep your hands on the keyboard and not grab the mouse, you can alt-tab to whatever that selects and then alt-tab to come back and you'll be in the save dialog. Hacky, but it keeps your hands down until they fix this

Comment: Another way of focusing the popup is to use the Alt+~ (tilde) window switch instead of the Alt+Tab app switch as suggested above. Of course that works best if you have a single Chrome window opened cause otherwise you will be switching between the actual Chrome windows instead.

Comment: Also file upload dialog is out of focus and it always defaults to home folder.

Answer (score 7):

This unfortunately [is a bug](https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk/issues/137#issuecomment-1090119458), probably with `xdg-desktop-portal`. It affects some applications in any containerized format, not only snap, but also flatpak and appimage. Mouse users will not quickly see it, but it is an enormous annoyance for keyboard oriented users. Firefox and Thunderbird (containerized) are affected too.

The bug is around for some time already, and is still not solved in the forthcoming Ubuntu 22.04. In the current Ubuntu LTS, 20.04,it works fine though.

Xorg users can use `devilspie` or `devilspie2` to work around this bug (with credit [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2478830&p=14112414#post14112414)). A `devilspie2` rule that will automatically focus xdg-desktop-portal dialogs is:

```
if ( get_application_name() == 'xdg-desktop-portal-gnome' and get_window_type() == 'WINDOW_TYPE_DIALOG' )
then
    focus_window();
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this, how do I add this script to "devilspie"? If you would be so kind?

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on @vanadium's answer, here are all the steps for the Ubuntu:

1. Install devilspie2 with: `sudo apt install devilspie2`
2. Add it to startup programs:

   - Open "Startup Applications" in Ubuntu
   - Press `Add`
   - As a `Name` enter `Devilspie2`
   - As a `Command` enter `devilspie2` for it to to start at startup
   - Finish by clicking `Add`
3. Create a script for `devilspie2` to execute

   - `vim ~/.config/devilspie2/devilspie2.lua`
   - Paste in the following script:

     ```
      if ( get_application_name() == 'xdg-desktop-portal-gnome' and get_window_type() == 'WINDOW_TYPE_DIALOG' )
      then
          focus_window();
      end
     ```
4. Log out and log in again for `devilspie2` to start working

---

Works on Xorg, doesn't work on Wayland, credits to [original answer](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2478830&page=2&p=14112414#post14112414) on ubuntuforums

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix but a workaround: you can make it focus by holding <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> without releasing it, then you switch back with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>.

At least on Ubuntu 22.04.3

Answer (score -3):

"... anybody could advice me how to fix it under Ubuntu 21.04."

My apologies if this sounds trivial, but I think it is the only way:

1. File a bug, and wait for someone to fix it.
2. Fix it yourself.
3. Try updating chrome.

**Note**: I don't see that behaviour with either of the following systems

1. System 1: Ubuntu 20.04.3

   1.1. Chrome Version 94.0.4606.54 (Official Build) (64-bit)

   1.2. Chromium Version 95.0.4638.69 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)
2. System 2: Lubuntu 20.04.3

   2.1. Chrome Version 95.0.4638.69 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I know this Ubuntu version was not quoted, but it is in-between 18.04.6 Mate and 21.04, which were quoted... it is quite strange.

Comment: Very useful answer. Bug is filed. It is reproducible even in 21.10. Not a way to get a bounty.

Comment: @N0rbert - That is my minimal contribution... evidence towards the fact that the bug is not *that* reproducible, I guess. Unless 21.04 / 21.10 / Mate 18.04.6 have something specifically different from 20.04.3. Others may give their experiences.

Comment: I'm still facing this issue. Is there any update on the bug? Or a link I can follow?