# Editing filename in Firefox searches upon input

Tags: firefox, 22.04

I've been a long-time Linux and Ubuntu user and recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. One very annoying thing now is that whenever I'm trying to save a page or print to pdf from  Firefox, if I try to edit the filename, the input will always switch to search with anything I type instead of changing the filename. This may be unrelated to Firefox but that has been where I felt the problem so...

Was there some setting that changed recently? Perhaps some GTK thing? I know that now Firefox is installed as a snap; could that be the problem somehow?

Note, by upgraded I mean, that I did a fresh install but keep all the files in my home, which is kept in a separate partition. Also, in case it matters, I'm using the mate desktop.

Edit: There are some previous questions before on keyboard operation and certain buttons not having the default focus when they should. My question is different in the sense that I'm unable to edit the filename before saving because of the constant change in focus. The only workaround thus far involves opening a separate text editor, typing the name I want and then copy and paste.

Comment: Little users seem to notice this annoying bug, which is due to xdg-desktop-portal-gtk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Chrome browser "Save as" dialog to be on focus when opening under Ubuntu 21.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366735/how-to-make-chrome-browser-save-as-dialog-to-be-on-focus-when-opening-under-ub)

Comment: The problem is indeed related to Firefox being a snap, but the issue is not limited to snap: it affects all containerized applications, and I guess only when using GTK4 file dialogs.

Comment: @vanadium Although the problem mentioned in that question may be related, it is different than the one I describe. I'm ok using the mouse. Now imagine that one selects the filename text box and every time one types, the focus changes to a search box and that that text appears in there instead. Again and again...
It seems that the only solution is to nix Firefox through snap and install it manually.

Comment: I see. I removed the close vote. I cannot reproduce that particular issue, though.

Comment: I appreciate you looking into it. I'll try starting with a brand new Firefox profile later today. If the problem is resolved, I'll report it here.

Comment: Linking identical issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431877/the-save-as-dialog-does-not-let-me-type-a-file-name-how-can-i-fix-that#comment2506229_1431877

Answer (score 2):

This a [known GNOME bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/2638) that's been around for quite a while and is related to the file chooser, not Firefox. The good news is that, [according to GNOME developer Luca Bacci](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/2638#note_1519856), the bug will be fixed in the next GTK release:

> Hi Thomas! Are you experiencing issue #4880 (closed) in Ubuntu 22.04? If so, that is going to be fixed in the next GTK stable release. This issue was closed automatically by GitLab, but the fix has not yet arrived to distros.

Although the problem will be gone in the next GTK release, I have no idea what Ubuntu version this will ship with though or if it will be ported to 22.04. Till then, I don't think you can do something to workaround this admittedly annoying issue.

Comment: Don't think this is fixed yet, but it is super annoying