# The Save As dialog does not let me type a file name. How can I fix that?

Tags: 22.04, snap, gui, i3-wm, dialog

[image]

In some programs like Firefox (Snap), if I trigger **Save as...** a dialog opens. If I try to modify the file name, I can move the caret with the cursor keys but as soon as I press any key to enter text, a filter box is shown to filter the listed file names so I can't specify the file name.

This happens since I updated to Ubuntu 22.04. It is very irritating. I always have to save with the default name, then find the file on the disk and rename it.

I am using i3wm in case that matters. Anyone has an idea about how to fix this?

Comment: are you using FF snap or APT? I use the APT version in v22.04 and it works fine. [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: @24601 this is with 99% certainty the default snap version of 22.04.

Comment: There are issues with file dialogs used via xdg-portal-gtk. Indeed, that you use i3wm does matter. Can you click with the mouse in the name field then type the name? If the dialog has keyboard focus, then - as a workaround - Alt+n should focus the name field and allow you to type a file name. Perhaps using devilspie2 to automatically bring these dialogs in focus may fully work around the issue. Cannot test, lacking i3.

Comment: It is the snap version @24601 I don't see an APT version available.

Comment: @vanadium I can click with the mouse and the caret blinks there waiting for me. As soon as I type one character, the character is entered but the filter box pops up capturing the focus. Alt+n has the same effect: I can only type one character. My medium term solution will be to switch to Arch (in my next computer) which I've used for 7 years in a laptop without troubles. Then I don't need to deal with Snap or big updates. Still, would be good to find a workaround :)

Comment: [this reference](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04) shows how to remove the snap and replace with APT version of FF

Comment: Thank you @24601 ! I'll check that out.

Comment: Solved by removing the Snap! Thank you! My life is a bit better thanks to you @24601 :)

Comment: By the way... how can snap be so slow even when removing a package. It took like one minute on a decent computer.

Comment: Just to point out that the asker is the only one having the problem: I have the exact same problem on Firefox 106 on Ubuntu 22.04, and this already for the last half year. I am also using `i3`.

Comment: Linking identical issue that explains it'll be fixed in a future GTK version: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413900/editing-filename-in-firefox-searches-upon-input

Answer (score 2):

My issue is solved by [replacing the Firefox Snap with the APT version](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04) (thank you @24601)

According to @vanadium it seems to be related to `Snap`, `i3wm` and `xdg-portal-gtk`. I checked other snaps and the issue is present in `chromium`, but not in `code`, `blender` or `signal-desktop`.

Comment: This is not a solution. It is a workaround.

Comment: Thank you. Removing snap and installing it from the apt repository solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

On an Ubuntu 22.04 (newly updated from 18.04) box I got Firefox and Chromium browser back to using the good, system SaveAs dialog box instead of the horrid (((search box focus grabber and almost impossible to change file name from the default))) dialog box by doing this:

```
sudo snap install snapd
```

This version of snapd, 2.38.3, apparently overrides the apt-installed snapd version 2.38.

That the snap version of snapd wasn't installed ("`snap list`" did not list it) was the glaring difference between the bad box and a laptop that did not have the problem.

I should note, the about:config setting, `widget.use-xdg-desktop-portal.file-picker` needs to be put back to the default, `2`, from `0`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sadly, on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, 'snap version' shows that I am at snapd version 2.58.3, and I have checked that my setting for widget.use-xdg-desktop-portal.file-picker is 2, but I still see the problem described in the original post.

Comment: That is sad, KneadToKnow. Very. Noticing that I didn't have the snap-installed version was about the last of the things different between my two machines, one with the problem, one without. I suppose it might make magical sense to check that you have snapd in the "snap list"? Desperation. :)

Comment: Output from 'snap list' shows snapd version 2.58.3.

Comment: Well, my Firefox started using the bad SaveAs dialog box. Sigh. I must have run out of the eye of newt.

Comment: For what it's worth, changing `widget.use-xdg-desktop-portal.file-picker` **to** `0` fixed this issue for me.  It had been set to the default `2`, and I had the bad file picker with this question's issue.  After changing the setting to `0`, I have a fully-functional save-as dialog in which I can type and edit a filename.

Comment: Foo. I fixed mine in the same way some time ago. Sorry for not suggesting it. On mine, the dialog box window is the same, ugly, thing, but at least the file name can be changed by typing.