# Open / Save file dialog windows changed after upgrade 20.04->22.04 and they are broken, how to fix?

Tags: system, filemanager, dialog

These are the 2 biggest problems with the new Open and Save file dialog windows:

1. Open files: The 20.04 version of this dialog always showed a preview of image files on the right side when I clicked that file. This was very extremely nice and useful but is gone.
2. Save files: When I want to change the filename in the Save file dialog, I can't. It starts to search for what I type in, even if I click into the "Name" field first, sometimes I can type 1 letter there but then the search function kicks in again.

I hate to say that, but I want to get the old file dialogs back. :(

Comment: The "open files" dialog is a change in GTK4, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406730/icon-view-in-google-chrome-file-chooser-is-gone-on-ubuntu-22-04 Someone said that the GTK developers are apparently *finally* working on showing thumbnails in the dialog, but no idea when that will be ready. The other issue is also a known bug, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413900/editing-filename-in-firefox-searches-upon-input