# right click save as in Firefox 104

Tags: firefox, files

Ubuntu 22.04 Mate. I thought this was a Firefox bug. It isn't. Right click on an image in the browser. Save as. The save as pop-up comes up. The focus is on it. Type in a name for the file and press the enter/save box. Repeat the process. The focus on the save as dialog is not on the dialog. You have to click on the title bar to get the focus on the dialog box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). We do not accept bug reports. If you believe you have found a bug in Ubuntu, please file a bug report through official channels so that developers can investigate the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a highly visible, keyboard usability affecting issue that is four years old, still unfixed, and affecting applications that use xdg-desktop-portal to show native file dialogs in among others Gnome Shell and Mate (however not XFCE). That includes some containerized applications  (snap, flatpak and AppImage alike), but also some applications installed using the standard APT system such as Chromium and Google Chrome: https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk/issues/137#issuecomment-1090119458

The snap version of Firefox in Ubuntu 22.04 uses xdg-desktop-portal, so it is affected.

There is no solution until the developers fix this. For Firefox - and other applications that can be substituted by a regular install which does not use xdg-desktop-portal, [changing to the regular .deb version](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/558158) allows to avoid the issue.

For users on Xorg, devilspie or devilspie2 can be used to [work around the bug](https://askubuntu.com/a/1402545/558158).

Comment: Per that "changing to the regular .deb version" link, users on 22.04 must follow extra steps to switch the Firefox source - the official repository installs the snap version.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Indeed, that was not the best link. I changed it to a better answer, which does not remove snap but prevents the snap version of firefox to be installed.