# Save dialog is not focused after upgrading to 22.04

Tags: 22.04

After I upgraded Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04, Save dialog is not focused after it opens and I have to click on it to make it focused. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [right click save as in Firefox 104](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426055/right-click-save-as-in-firefox-104)

Comment: No, because it's not only in Firefox. So the bug is not from Firefox itself. The Save dialog has got erroneous.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Chrome browser "Save as" dialog to be on focus when opening under Ubuntu 21.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366735/how-to-make-chrome-browser-save-as-dialog-to-be-on-focus-when-opening-under-ub)

Comment: yes, thank you.