# Why does "Save" not have keyboard control? (Google Chrome on Ubuntu 22.04.1)

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, 22.04

I'm using Google Chrome on Ubuntu 22.04.1. When I save a page (or use ctrl-s), the resulting save dialogue is full page. I am unable to use keyboard navigation. E.g., I cannot use esc or enter to close the dialogue. I am able to do an esc/enter via a touch-pad click, so in principle the dialogue works. This has been like this since the upgrade to 22.04.

Have anybody else experienced this?

Comment: YES!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This question turns out to be a duplicate. For xorg, answers here:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2478830&page=2&p=14112414#post14112414
[How to make Chrome browser "Save as" dialog to be on focus when opening under Ubuntu 21.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366735/how-to-make-chrome-browser-save-as-dialog-to-be-on-focus-when-opening-under-ub) (not solution for wayland).

This is a bug, affecting several applications, including chrome.

Work around:

```
sudo apt install devilspie2
```

Create the file

```
~/.config/devilspie2/devilspie2.lua
```

put this in the file:

```
if ( get_application_name() == 'xdg-desktop-portal-gnome' and get_window_type() == 'WINDOW_TYPE_DIALOG' )
then
    focus_window();
end
```

Then run

```
> devilspie2
```

In chrome, you can now use `ctrl-s`, followed by `enter` to save pages.