# In 22.04.03 LTS, When Opening "Save As..." or "Open..." Dialogs from Browsers, Focus Remains in Original Window, Preventing Keyboard Navigation

Tags: keyboard, browser, gtk3, dialog, xdg

In previous version of Ubuntu, I was able to use keyboard navigation when saving files in a "Save as...", and similarly when opening files.

However, as of the update to 22.04, whenever I open one of these files from a browser (I have tested Chrome, Chromium, and Firefox and they all have the same problem, but LibreOffice does not have this problem, if it helps troubleshoot) the original window keeps the focus. This makes it so that I cannot use the keyboard to navigate in the window, without first using the mouse to click in the new window. I cannot even click "Enter" to save the file, which is the most frequent thing I want to do. As a hack / workaround I have found I can hit Alt-Tab twice, which seems to bring the focus to the dialog. However, this is unintuitive and is burdensome, adding two new keystrokes and slowing down a lot of actions I do frequently.

I notice that someone reported a similar issue, with 21, using Chrome:

[How to make Chrome browser "Save as" dialog to be on focus when opening under Ubuntu 21.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366735/how-to-make-chrome-browser-save-as-dialog-to-be-on-focus-when-opening-under-ub)

And in this case it was considered to be a bug, but that post is from nearly two years ago, and people are posting on the thread and it is still not fixed. The only workaround I saw requires installation of an additional software package, devilspie, and use of a custom script with it to override the default behavior, something I would rather avoid.

It also looks like the relevant newer version of software which introduced this bug was forced onto LTS users, without addressing this problem. This seems like a major oversight to me, especially since there are also a long list of other things that are broken with the interface, which I plan to address in other questions.

Is there any way to fix this behavior? Or do I just need to report this to the proper channels and hope that it gets fixed, which I'm not particularly hopeful about given that it looks like it's already gone nearly two years without being fixed, in spite of quite a lot of people complaining about it? Is there any way I can speed the process of that bug getting fixed, or revert back to an earlier version of software where the Dialog box and focus behaves as expected?

Comment: This happens to applications that use the XDG portal, like snaps and some non GTK programs that invoke native GTK dialogs. I agree with you: this is a major useability issue, and should not be there for years in an LTS.